# Images grey until clicked - change to color and remembers clicked images

Tags: java, android

When my user lands on the main activity for the first time I want the tiles(imageviews) to be greyed out and unclickable. Only the first tile should be in color and clickable. After the user accesses the first tile and returns to the main activity the next tile will become colored and clickable and so on.

The idea is to guide the user through the sequence on ther first time using the app. Im guessing this information will need to be stored in shared preferences as I only want this to happen the first time. Subsequent times all tiles should be in color and clickable.

Could someone help me achieve this? Currently I have a switch statement, a boolean and color/grey versions of the image tiles.

```
 @Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    SharedPreferences.Editor introEditor = introPref.edit();

    switch (v.getId()) {

        case R.id.cbt_button_grey:
            Intent mainIntent = new Intent(getActivity(), IntroActivity2.class);
            startActivity(mainIntent);
            hasSelected = true;
            introEditor.putBoolean("hasSelected", hasSelected);
            introEditor.commit();
            break;
        case R.id.twisted_thinking_button_grey:
            hasSelected = true;
            Intent distortedIntent = new Intent(getActivity(), TwelveTypesDistortedThinkingSliderActivity.class);
            startActivity(distortedIntent);
            break;
        case R.id.workout_button_grey:
            hasSelected = true;
            Fragment workoutFragment = new WorkoutFragment();
            FragmentTransaction workoutTransaction = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            workoutTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, workoutFragment);
            workoutTransaction.commit();
            break;
        case R.id.workout_log_button_grey:
            hasSelected = true;
            Fragment workoutLogFragment = new WorkoutLogFragment();
            FragmentTransaction workoutLogTransaction = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            workoutLogTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, workoutLogFragment);
            workoutLogTransaction.commit();
            break;
        case R.id.mood_log_button:
            hasSelected = true;
            Fragment moodLogFragment = new MoodLogFragment();
            FragmentTransaction moodLogTransaction = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            moodLogTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, moodLogFragment);
            moodLogTransaction.commit();
            break;
        case R.id.activities_button_grey:
            hasSelected = true;
            Fragment activitiesFragment = new ActivitiesFragment();
            FragmentTransaction activitiesTransaction = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            activitiesTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, activitiesFragment);
            activitiesTransaction.commit();
            break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about using startActivityForResult() in MainActivity class. You can override onActivityResult() to make the Images enabled/disabled. It is just a suggestion.